# Automatic transmission sticking after car has not been driven for 3 months

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, idle, long-term-storage

My car has not been driven for a while and it is having trouble and sticking when shifting gears. Should I continue to drive it and will this problem fix itself or is there something I can buy like an oil additive or does it need a service?

It didn't stick before I stopped driving it.

Comment: What is the year and model of the vehicle? How many miles?

Answer (score 3):

You can try Zmax Micro lubricant it's trusted by many automotive television shows. It was used by the late great automotive guru Carroll Shelby. It should work well  since Carroll suggested the brand and put it in his own cars that went off the showroom floor, according to the commercial.

Here is a video link that explains and demonstrates what Zmax does for transmissions. All credit goes to the people in the video and the Zmax Youtube channel and Zmax itself

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcNs-Fc8V_Y

Comment: While Zmax may be an awesome product (I have no clue or reference one way or the other), please realize all of those product endorsements are paying for the TV shows. Do you think Mr. Shelby wasn't getting paid for that? Would Michael Jordan not get paid for putting Nike's on his feet back in the day? Different sport; same game.

Comment: I made a change to my answer. Please see the info and video above.

Comment: No worries ... I wasn't dogging you out, just making sure you are aware. Thanks for being here and for posting!

Comment: You're welcome. I understand. I would like to compliment you on the Camaro ZL1 logo you have on your profile. Carroll Shelby, John DeLorean, Don Yenko, and Steve Saleen are my favorite pioneers in the field.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a newer car and doesnt have a CVT, I would recommend doing an oil change on the tranny and add a new filter throw some lucal tranny fluid in it, then take it for a drive a long one about atleast half an hour, and do city driving for about 15 inutes, this might fix it.

If that did not take care of that then you might have some sticky solenoids or some other problems.